# How can I use jquery (or other javascript) to parse data from iTunes-formatted podcast XML feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing, itunes

I found the demo at think2loud.com that shows how to use jquery to parse an XML file.  I have downloaded the source files and uploaded them to my own server and it works fine.  A soon as I try to apply it to my own xml file (iTunes podcast feed) I don't get any output.  I'm kind of in over my head, I think.

What I'd like is to have ***ONLY THE FIRST*** podcast info displayed in the following format:

< a href = path to file . mp3 > Title of message< / a >

**Description of message**

where:

GUID is path to file

TITLE is Title of Message

ITUNES:SUBTITLE is Description of message

Here's a sample of the demo code I'd like to tweak:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sites.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('site').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                    $('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                    $(this).find('desc').each(function(){
                        var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
                        var long = $(this).find('long').text();
                        $('<div class="brief"></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                        $('<div class="long"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

and here's an excerpt of the XML file I'd like to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/podcast.xml" />
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 15 Aug 2011 13:30:32 -0300</lastBuildDate>
    <title>Deep Water Podcast</title>
    <itunes:author>AJ Thomas</itunes:author>
    <link>http://www.deepwaterchurch.com</link>

    <generator>Podcast Maker v1.4.1 - http://www.lemonzdream.com/podcastmaker</generator>
    <description><![CDATA[The weekly message from Deep Water Church in Halifax, Nova Scotia.]]></description>
    <itunes:subtitle />
    <itunes:summary>The weekly message from Deep Water Church in Halifax, Nova Scotia.</itunes:summary>
    <language>en</language>
    <copyright>2007 Deep Water Church</copyright>
    <image>

        <url>http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/podcast_144.jpg</url>
        <title>Deep Water Podcast</title>
        <link>http://www.deepwaterchurch.com</link>
        <width>144</width>
        <height>144</height>
    </image>

    <itunes:image href="http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/podcast.jpg" />
    <category>Christianity</category>
    <itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
        <itunes:category text="Christianity" />
    </itunes:category>
    <category>Spirituality</category>
    <itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
        <itunes:category text="Spirituality" />

    </itunes:category>
    <category>Non-Profit</category>
    <itunes:category text="Government &amp; Organizations">
        <itunes:category text="Non-Profit" />
    </itunes:category>
    <itunes:keywords>deep water, deepwater, church, halifax, nova scotia, canada, jesus, aj thomas</itunes:keywords>
    <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>

    <item>
        <title>Hurry Up and Wait - Slow Down</title>
        <itunes:author>Deep Water</itunes:author>
        <description><![CDATA[Episode 2 of 2. Luke 10:38-42. A life that is ministry isn't just about being busy all the time-- we need to take time to sit at Jesus' feet and be quiet, too.]]></description>
        <itunes:subtitle>Episode 2 of 2. Luke 10:38-42. A life that is ministry isn&apos;t just about being busy all the time-- we need to take time to sit at Jesus&apos; feet and be quiet, too.</itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:summary />

        <enclosure url="http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/Jen%20Ochej-August%2014%2C%202011.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" length="16625879" />
        <guid>http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/Jen%20Ochej-August%2014%2C%202011.mp3</guid>
        <pubDate>Mon, 15 Aug 2011 13:29:03 -0300</pubDate>
        <category>Christianity</category>
        <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:duration>00:34:34</itunes:duration>

        <itunes:keywords>deep water, deepwater, church, halifax, nova scotia, canada, jesus, aj thomas</itunes:keywords>
    </item>
```

The link to the demo I've been playing with is [here](http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/testing)

Like I mentioned, I'd like this to pull only the most recently updated podcast (first "item") from the list.  I'm clearly in over my head!  I'd appreciate some guidance.  Thanks tons.

---

Ok, I've got it working... kind of.  I have it appending to the "body", but I'd like to assign it to a specific DIV, like the original example.  When I try to set the `link.appendTo('body');` to `link.appendTo('podcast');` I get no output. **EDIT: I figured that part out.  Still need help with the next question, though.**

Secondarily, I'd like to be able to have a description of the episode ("itunes:subtitle" in the XML file) placed under the link.  Can we make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $.get('sites.xml',
          function(xml)
          {
            var item=$('channel > item:first',xml);
            if(item.length)
            {
              var link=$('<a/>').attr('href',$('enclosure',item).attr('url'))
                                .text($('title',item).text());
                  //put it where you want to
                  link.appendTo('body');
            }
          },
          'xml')
  }
);
```

Returns for me right now for http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/podcast.xml

```
<a href="http://www.deepwaterchurch.com/podcast/Jen%20Ochej-August%2014%2C%202011.mp3">Hurry Up and Wait - Slow Down</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.  I'm very much a novice at javascript and jquery; I put the code in the head of my HTML document, which is in the same directory as "podcast.xml".  I changed the "$.get('sites.xml'," to "$.get('podcast.xml'," and I get nothing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I've tested it before posting it, I'm pretty sure that it works. Check the response using firebug's network-tab, what do you receive?

Comment: Parsing "itunes" elements requires escaping the colon in the tag identifier otherwise the colon is seen as a selector filter e.g. the selector for `<itunes:subtitle>` should be `xml.find("itunes\\3Asubtitle")` You can find more on that here https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: For jquery I have to do something like `$xml.find("itunes\\:subtitle")` instead.